# Why does Image.GetThumbnailImage work differently on IIS6 and IIS7.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis-6, iis-7.5

Bit of a strange question and I don't know whether anyone will have come across this one before.

We have a ASP.net page generating physical thumbnail jpeg files on a filesystem and copying fullsize images to a different location. So we input one image and we get a complete copy in one location and a small image 102*68 in a different location.

We're currently looking to finally move away from IIS6 on Server 2003 to IIS7.5 on Server 2008R2, except there's on problem.

On the old system (so IIS6/Server 2003) the black borders are removed and the image stays at the correct ration. On the new system (IIS7.5/Server 2008) the thumbnails are rendered exactly as they exist in the JPEG, with black borders, but this makes the thumbnail slightly squashed and obviously includes ugly black borders.

Anyone know why this might be happening? I've done a google and can't seem to find out which behaviour is "correct". My gut tells me that the new system is correctly rendering the thumbnail as it exists, but I don't know.

Anyone have any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: Perhaps IIS7.5 is defaulting to a newer version of .net than IIS6, so perhaps it's a change in .net instead?

Comment: It's more possible that the .NET Framework version is causing the difference. But it could be the server software as well. Have you troubleshooted yet? Are both running same version of .NET?

Comment: Where should I be looking for this? The IIS7.5 app pool is set to .Net 2... is that the only place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as suggested it is the .net differences.  not IIS.

Just re write your code, your save a lot of time, very simple thing to do.

Here is a image handler i wrote a while ago that re draws any image to your settings.

```
public class image_handler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // set file
    string ImageToDraw = context.Request.QueryString["FilePath"];
    ImageToDraw = context.Server.MapPath(ImageToDraw);


    // Grab images to work on's true width and height
    Image ImageFromFile = Image.FromFile(ImageToDraw);
    double ImageFromFileWidth = ImageFromFile.Width;
    double ImageFromFileHeight = ImageFromFile.Height;
    ImageFromFile.Dispose();

    // Get required width and work out new dimensions
    double NewHeightRequired = 230;

    if (context.Request.QueryString["imageHeight"] != null)
        NewHeightRequired = Convert.ToDouble(context.Request.QueryString["imageHeight"]);

    double DivTotal = (ImageFromFileHeight / NewHeightRequired);
    double NewWidthValue = (ImageFromFileWidth / DivTotal);
    double NewHeightVale = (ImageFromFileHeight / DivTotal);

    NewWidthValue = ImageFromFileWidth / (ImageFromFileWidth / NewWidthValue);
    NewHeightVale = ImageFromFileHeight / (ImageFromFileHeight / NewHeightVale);


    // Set new width, height
    int x = Convert.ToInt16(NewWidthValue);
    int y = Convert.ToInt16(NewHeightVale);

    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(x, y);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    Image thumbnail = Image.FromFile(ImageToDraw);

    // Quality Control
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.DrawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, x, y);
    g.Dispose();

    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    image.Dispose();
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it's the .net differences, but surely the code (which is pre-compiled) is built against a version of .net and the (apparently) non-existent .net setting in IIS has no bearing?

Comment: yes that right, you are compiling your code against .net CLR, the difference is in how the new servers version of CLR is handling your old code. Also .net can be in many states, a fix here an up date here. so a new server with a fresh .net 2 install on it can be different to and old server that has had many updates and upgraded leaving you unsure as to what .net version you actual have. I would personally re write the code. A lot of servers only run what they need, so you have a view that it is a complete working version, when in most cases it is not,it works for the job it was tasked.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you. It's legacy code, stuff we're looking to dump soon anyway, so I think the consensus of opinion here is to just leave it for now. It's not causing us a major problem for now. That being said, I believe your answer is valid "Just re write your code, your save a lot of time, very simple thing to do." Much easier than trying to work out the mysteries of IIS... With that in mind I'll be marking your answer as the accepted answer (not least because it is the only one!)